# How to access key-value from JSON response

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I was trying to get the `sid` and `date_created` from the JSON response of Twilio after sending a text message but they are always `undefined`.

I've also tried `body.['sid']` and `body.['date_created']` but they still don't return the correct values.

## Code

```
const textMe = function sendSms() {
  request.post(options, (err, resp, body) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('error:', err);
    } else {
      console.log('statusCode:', resp.statusCode);
      console.log('sid:', body.sid);
      console.log('dateCreated:', body.date_created);
    }
  });
};

textMe();
```

## Expectation

```
statusCode: 201
sid: SMxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
dateCreated: Sat, 10 Jun 2017 14:55:14 +0000
```

## Reality

```
statusCode: 201
sid: undefined
dateCreated: undefined
```

## JSON Response from console.log(body)

```
{"sid": "SMxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "date_created": "Sat, 10 Jun 2017 14:55:14 +0000", "date_updated": "Sat, 10 Jun 2017 14:55:14 +0000", "date_sent": null, "account_s
id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "to": "+xxxxxxxxxxxx", "from": "+xxxxxxxxxxxx", "messaging_service_sid": null, "body": "Sent from your Twilio trial account - Twilio Test using
Node.js and request.", "status": "queued", "num_segments": "1", "num_media": "0", "direction": "outbound-api", "api_version": "2010-04-01", "price": null, "price_unit": "USD", "error_cod
e": null, "error_message": null, "uri": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/xxxxxxxxxxxx/Messages/xxxxxxxxxxxx.json", "subresource_uris": {"media": "/2010-0
4-01/Accounts/xxxxxxxxxxxx/Messages/xxxxxxxxxxxx/Media.json"}}
```

EDIT:

## Working Code

```
const textMe = function sendSms() {
  request.post(options, (err, resp, body) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('error:', err);
    } else {
      console.log('statusCode:', resp.statusCode);
      console.log('sid:', JSON.parse(body).sid);
      console.log('dateCreated:', JSON.parse(body).date_created);
    }
  });
};

textMe();
```

Comment: you'll have to show the JSON you get if you want help with the JSON you get

Comment: Try res.body...

Comment: how about you `console.log(body)` to see what it is before blindly expecting it to be something it obviously isn't

Comment: Hello @JaromandaX! I've edited my post. Please see the JSON response. Thanks!

Comment: Tried body[0].sid ?

Comment: ok, and what is `console.log(body)` giving you

Comment: @JaromandaX, that's the whole response from the `console.log(body)`.

Comment: ok, well, I'm stumped then - wait, that's a string or an object?

Comment: @JaromandaX Okay, I get it now. Thanks for this! I'll edit my post. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your body still stringified? If so you will need to JSON.parse(body) to access properties in the JSON object.